# Unable to access structure members through pointer in function called form another funciton?

Tags: c, microchip, programming, function

While trying to interface [BMP180](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST-BMP180-DS000-09.pdf) to my STM32L4 Controller using [libraries](https://github.com/BoschSensortec/BMP180_driver) I found that the ,

```
BMP180_RETURN_FUNCTION_TYPE bmp180_get_calib_param(void)
```

funciton called from

```
BMP180_RETURN_FUNCTION_TYPE bmp180_init(struct bmp180_t *bmp180)
```

is unable to access the structure member through the pointer.

The `BMP180_RETURN_FUNCTION_TYPE bmp180_init(struct bmp180_t *bmp180)` takes the structure address and assign it to a pointer,`static struct bmp180_t *p_bmp180;` declared  globally in  bmp180.c. 
 For Example : `p_bmp180->calib_param.ac1 =(something)` is not actually making any change to the structure member, whereas it changes in the init function( `BMP180_RETURN_FUNCTION_TYPE bmp180_init(struct bmp180_t *bmp180)`), where the address of the structure is received from bmp180_support.c.

What could be a reason for this and how to solve it?
The IDE used is KeilMDK-V5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because the the optimization level in the 
project options in the Keil-MDK was set to level 3,
when I lowered it to level 1 ,everything worked fine; there was nothing
wrong with the code.

Comment: If the code is correct then the optimization level should modify the behavior of the code.. So your code must be broken in some subtle way..

Comment: Agreed, either undefined behaviour in the code, or a bug in the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

> The BMP180_RETURN_FUNCTION_TYPE bmp180_init(struct bmp180_t *bmp180) takes the structure address and assign it to a pointer,static struct bmp180_t *p_bmp180;

The syntax is just wrong.

Comment: Hi,static struct bmp180_t *p_bmp180; is the global declaration of the pointer  . p_bmp180 = bmp180Add; This is how the pointer is assigned